# Is it possible to dsallow excess properties on a function callback return type

Tags: typescript, types

In the following example, is there a way  to dissallow excess properties? I need typescript to throw if the callback returns an object that has more properties than the Foo interface

```
interface Foo {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

type GetFoo = ()=> Foo

const baz = (getFoo : GetFoo) => {
    return getFoo()
}

baz(()=>({
    id: 1,
    name: '',
    a: 1, // this should produce an error
}))
```

Comment: It's not really possible; there are things you can do to discourage excess properties but nothing foolproof.  See the answer to the linked question for more info